# How to introduce a vertical line between toolbar items using wxpython

Tags: wxpython, toolbar

i have created toolbar  with new and open items. toolbar size is (16x16).How could i introduce a vertical line between these toolbar items?

```
   self.newToolItem = self.toolBar.AddTool(wx.ID_NEW,'New', \
                         wx.Bitmap(wx.Bitmap("new.png")),"New")
    self.frameinst.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL,onNew,self.newToolItem)

    # how to introduce a vertical line between between these toolbar items # as a separation between these toolbar items 

    self.openToolItem = self.toolBar.AddTool(wx.ID_OPEN,'Open',\
                            wx.Bitmap(wx.Bitmap("open.png")), "Open")
    self.frameinst.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL,onOpen,self.openToolItem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.toolBar = self.frameInst.CreateToolBar()

issue resolved by adding separator(below line of code works) between toolbar items.

self.toolBar.AddSeparator()

we can introduce this line of code , where ever you want a separation between toolbar items.